# Android TextView ellipsize:end and gravity:right does not seem to work

Tags: android, textview

I want a right-aligned TextView with ellipsize on the end of text, but it does not seem to work:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in order for ellipses to show up, the whole area of the textview have to be filled, hence, the "effect" of right alignment + ellipses will never happen, if you want to accomplish this effect, what you have to do is set a small size for the text and then set a margin-left to push it to left of whatever layout you are using. Take on count that the OS will pop the ellipses only if the max width of the text has been overflowed losing here the "right" gravity effect...

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_gravity="right"`